# How I can manage the users IOS in-app subscription for my app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I have done some research but I can't find if apple has a way to manage my customer in-app subscription to do refund and cancel.

I look in itunes connect but I can't find any menus or informations about it.

In the developper documentation, I found that a **user** can manage is subscription in itunes by openning the link :
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions

I also found that to do a refund the users need to contact the Apple customer service in the working with subcription cancellation part. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

In the android console, there is menu to manage the order for the app and cancel or refund an order. So, if a customer call us we can do the refund on our side.

[image: order management]
[image: remove subscription]

Comment: No, the methods you have discovered are the only methods; Cancellation is performed using the subscription management site; you can provide a link to that in your app.  Only Apple can refund a subscription.